# consuming a RESTful service

Tags: android

I found this class someone has created:

http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/

It looks like exactly what I need, however, being the newbie that I am, I do not know how to utilize this class.

I tried initializing an instance by doing RestClient myclient = new RestClient(); but I dont think that's right.

I just want to retrieve json from a service and parse it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing REST stuff, I highly recommend taking a look at the [SycnAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) class. The android team basically designed it with REST in mind and it's what most of the google apps use. Plus, there's an absolutely great [Google IO video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) that gives a high-level explination on how to use it (seriously, like one of my favorite videos).

Comment: +1. Check http://naked-code.blogspot.com/2011/05/revenge-of-syncadapter-synchronizing.html

Comment: That's an awesome explination. I wish I'd had that to walk me through the SampleSyncAdapter when I was first learning it.

Comment: that seems really complicated considering I just want to retrieve some json once the activity loads.

Comment: @Adam Fair enough. The SyncAdapter is really really complicated. It probably isn't right for you in this case then.

Answer (score 1):

RestClient looks like it only asslows static usage, as it doesn't have a constructor defined.  That means that you can't create a new class, but only access the methods via a static call.

Try using it like this:

```
RestClient.connect(url);
```

This method says void, so it won;t return anything.  If you need it to return something to use later, you will need to modify the method.

Comment: yea it uses log.i. but I dont see anything when I check logcat. The class doesnt work I guess

Comment: Seems a bit hasty to dismiss the class as a whole, though it certainly might need some tweaking.  Not seeing any of your code I wouldn't be able to tell why you can't see the logcat output.  Perhaps throw a bunch more logs in there, or run it through the debugger and post what you see if you get stuck.   My post modified for correctness, thanks @Josh Diehl.

Answer (score 0):

The class from the page you referenced is called `RestClient` not `RestKit`, that's the first issue. Additionally, that class is intended more as example code than something you can use.  Notice that the connect(String url) method is void so it doesn't return a result, and the connect code is just logging example strings.